# use Jsoup to extract html text, but returns unexpected result

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to write a web spider to extract the text from the html page, and I use Jsoup to parse the html, the simple code like below:

```
File file = new File("test2.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "utf-8");
System.out.println(doc.select("body").text());
```

the test2.html shown below:

[image]
the output is:

`hellothis is a simple testtest link 
        <!-- test here -->
        <ul>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test2</li>
            <li>test3</li>
            <li>test4</li>
            <li>test5</li>
            <li>test6</li>
        </ul>`

it seems that Jsoup take the code in textarea as all text.
How can I remove all the html tages, only keep the real text?

Comment: The behavior is corrent.You can parse the text in textarea again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fairjm has pointed out, this is the expected behavior.

If you inspect the `textarea` element with jsoup, you will find:

- it has only one childnode ([`doc.select("textarea").first().childNodeSize()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodeSize--) returns `1`)
- the childnode is a textnode ([`doc.select("textarea").first().childNode(0).nodeName()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#nodeName--) returns `#text`)

**Solution**

If you really just want to strip any tags - even if they are intentionally in textfields - **double parse** the content (*side-note: of course double parsing costs performance, but otherwise it should not have more drawbacks when only the text is targeted*):

```
File file = new File("test2.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "utf-8");
System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(doc.select("body").text(), "UTF-8").text());
```

**Output**

```
hellothis is a simple testtest link test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
```